# Ruby - Hash function with unknown number of arguments

Tags: ruby, hash, arguments

I'm trying to make a calorie counter for the below hash menu. in this example I've passed 3 arguments - what would the function need to look like it the number of parameters/arguments is unknown?

```
@menu = {
  "hamburger" => 250,
  "Cheese burger" => 350, 
  "cola" => 35, 
  "salad" => 120,
  "dessert" => 350
}
  
def order(a, b, c)
  return @menu[a] + @menu[b] + @menu[c]
end

puts order("hamburger", "Cheese burger", "cola")
```

```
tried 
def order(**a)
  total = 0
  total += @menu[**a]
end
```

i know (*a) works for arrays.

I'd like to be able to get results for
puts order("hamburger")
and equally for
puts order("Cheese burger", "salad"), for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby, it is often possible to write the code exactly the same way you would describe the solution in English. In this case, you need to get the **values at** specific keys of the hash and then compute the **sum** of the values.

You can use the [`Hash#values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) method to get the values at the specific keys and you can use the [`Array#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) method to compute the sum of the values:

```ruby
def order(*items)
  @menu.values_at(*items).sum
end
```

Note that it is strange to use an instance variable of the top-level `main` object. It would make much more sense to use a constant:

```ruby
MENU = {
  'hamburger'     => 250,
  'Cheese burger' => 350, 
  'cola'          => 35, 
  'salad'         => 120,
  'dessert'       => 350,
}

def order(*items)
  MENU.values_at(*items).sum
end
```

It would also make sense to [`freeze`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Object.html#method-i-freeze) the hash:

```ruby
MENU = {
  'hamburger'     => 250,
  'Cheese burger' => 350, 
  'cola'          => 35, 
  'salad'         => 120,
  'dessert'       => 350,
}.freeze
```

And last but not least, I find the name of the `order` method somewhat misleading. It is also ambiguous: is `order` meant to be a noun and this is meant to be a getter method that retrieves an order? Or is it meant to be a verb and it is meant to be a command method which tells the object to execute an order?

Either way, it does not seem that the method is doing either of those two things, rather it seems to compute a `total`. So, the name should probably reflect that.

Comment: Such good points! And makes a lot of sense, thank you for taking the time, Joerg!

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
MENU = {
  "hamburger" => 250,
  "Cheese burger" => 350, 
  "cola" => 35, 
  "salad" => 120,
  "dessert" => 350
}

def order(*args)
  MENU.values_at(*args).sum
end

order("hamburger", "Cheese burger", "cola")
#=> 635
```

Read about the [Ruby Splat Operator](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ruby-splat-operator), [`Hash#values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) and [`Array#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sum).

---

When you really want to use `each` (what I would not recommend), like mentioned in the comment, then you can implement it like this:

```
def order(*args)
  total = 0
  args.each { |name| total += MENU[name] }
  total
end
```

or

```
def order(*args)
  total = 0
  MENU.values_at(*args).each { |value| total += value }
  total
end
```

Comment: Brilliant - thank you! Do you know how this would work if I wanted to run the method with a .each? I'm not able to find any information online on what that would look like.
```
def order(*args)
  total = 0
  total += MENU.values_at(*args)
end
```

Comment: @AlHey I updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: thank you again! I really appreciate your time and insight